# How to put on a book launch?

Tags: planning

I have written a book (google 'Weave of the Ride') and I have built a community of followers of the past few years. I would like to put on a book launch. Does anyone have any tips and advice? I live in London so there are plenty of cafes. What sort of timescale from announcing it to the event happening? How many people should I invite and how is best to invite people? How many books should I have available for purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a website/blog? Put the launch up there, advertise it among your friends and they'll spread the word. 
Ask local cafes/bookshops if they'll be happy to host a launch, and see if the libraries would be happy to take a copy.
A friend of mine has just published her first book so I'm well versed in what to do!

Comment: Hi, I have created a page http://www.weaveoftheride.com/weave-book-launch, so you can see how I have approached my own question.